# Permission required for setting WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN in Android 6.0

Tags: android

Is there any sepcific permission required to be set in Manifest file while we are trying to set `WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN` in Android 6.0.

I try to set value to `WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN` using reflection because I am working in 2.3.3 environment. It throws a security exception when I try to invoke the SetGlobalSetting API passing value of setting `WIFI_DEVICE_OWNER_CONFIGS_LOCKDOWN` to it.